# how can I save the file in Map?

Tags: java, android

I working on dictionary app
I have file contain word and it's translation in row file. without split between them. 
I want to save them in Map in order to search for translation of the word. 
how can I save the file in Map?
and how map works?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the map as a sharedPreferences like this :

```
private void saveMap(Map<String,Boolean> inputMap){
  SharedPreferences pSharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyVariables", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  if (pSharedPref != null){
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(inputMap);
    String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();
    Editor editor = pSharedPref.edit();
    editor.remove("My_map").commit();
    editor.putString("My_map", jsonString);
    editor.commit();
  }
}
```

And load the map like this :

```
private Map<String,Boolean> loadMap(){
  Map<String,Boolean> outputMap = new HashMap<String,Boolean>();
  SharedPreferences pSharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyVariables", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  try{
    if (pSharedPref != null){       
      String jsonString = pSharedPref.getString("My_map", (new JSONObject()).toString());
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
      Iterator<String> keysItr = jsonObject.keys();
      while(keysItr.hasNext()) {
        String key = keysItr.next();
        Boolean value = (Boolean) jsonObject.get(key);
        outputMap.put(key, value);
      }
    }
  }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return outputMap;
}
```

Note that, `MyVariables` should be unique static string value.

Comment: excuse me, any line of the code tell the compiler which file to read data from?

Comment: SharedPreferences Api needs to key-value pairs to be able to store and load the data. Just check the official documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html and https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html